# INSERT STRING INTO JSON POSTGREE PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql

How to insert string value to json field in postgree?
json value :

```
my_json_record = "{'brandCode':'TOY',
'brandName':'TOYOTA',
'VehicleCollateral':{'ownerName':'Lode',
                       'CertificateNumber':'x123245'}
}"
```

I try to do this thing

```
$my_json_var = json_decode($my_json_record);
insert into jsonx(json) value
(
$my_json_var;
)
```

and found this error.
Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"

can you help with my problem?
Thx before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON requires double quotes (")

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-13